# I can not make all the Javascript calculation to work together for the total

Tags: javascript

I need to get the amount due when someone selects different options from different products. The calculation is right for the first checkbox until I select the second one which reset the calculation for the first box to zero.
Here's part of the code and on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samsh/ad1t3gmv/5/) as well. Sorry, the code is a bit long. I tried to make it shorter, but every time I messed up the code.

```js
"use strict";

var total = 0;
var price = 0;

var amountDue = document.getElementById("amountDue");

var selectOptions = document.getElementById("selectDesktop");
var selectOptionsPlus = document.getElementById("selectDesktopPlus");


function calculateTotal() {
    var desktopAddOn = document.getElementById("desktops");
    var desktopPlusAddOn = document.getElementById("desktopsPlus");

    var wirelessCardAddOn = document.getElementById("wirelessCard");
    var extraMemoryAddOn = document.getElementById("extraMemory");
    var speakersAddOn = document.getElementById("speakers");
    var surgeProtectorsAddOn = document.getElementById("surgeProtectors");
    var flashDriveAddOn = document.getElementById("flashDrive");
    var addSSDAddOn = document.getElementById("addSSD");

    var dTotal = 0;

    if (desktopAddOn.checked) {
        dTotal += 185;

        var iNumberofItems = selectOptions.options[selectOptions.selectedIndex].value;
        dTotal = Math.round(dTotal * iNumberofItems);
    }

    if (desktopPlusAddOn.checked) {
        dTotal += 85;

        var iNumberofItemsPlus = selectOptionsPlus.options[selectOptionsPlus.selectedIndex].value;
        dTotal = Math.round(dTotal * iNumberofItemsPlus);
    }

    if (wirelessCardAddOn.checked) {
        dTotal += 30;
    }
    if (extraMemoryAddOn.checked) {
        dTotal += 50;
    }
    if (speakersAddOn.checked) {
        dTotal += 30;
    }
    if (surgeProtectorsAddOn.checked) {
        dTotal += 5;
    }
    if (flashDriveAddOn.checked) {
        dTotal += 30;
    }
    if (addSSDAddOn.checked) {
        dTotal += 30;
    }
    amountDue.innerHTML = dTotal;
}

document.getElementById("desktops").addEventListener("change", function () {
    selectOptions.value = 1;
    calculateTotal();
});

document.getElementById("desktopsPlus").addEventListener("change", function () {
    selectOptions.value = 1;
    calculateTotal();
});

document.getElementById("wirelessCard").addEventListener("change", calculateTotal)
selectOptions.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);

document.getElementById("extraMemory").addEventListener("change", calculateTotal)
selectOptions.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);

document.getElementById("speakers").addEventListener("change", calculateTotal)
selectOptions.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);

document.getElementById("surgeProtectors").addEventListener("change", calculateTotal)
selectOptions.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);

document.getElementById("flashDrive").addEventListener("change", calculateTotal)
selectOptions.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);

document.getElementById("addSSD").addEventListener("change", calculateTotal)
selectOptions.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);
```

```html
            <div class="form-row products">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="chkYes1">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="desktops" name="" value="desktops" />
                        Desktops (1-9 Units) - $185.00 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
                <select id="selectDesktop" name="" class="form-control-sm">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!--  Desktops (10+ Units) -->
            <div class="form-row products">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="chkYes2">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="desktopsPlus" name="" value="desktopsPlus" />
                        Desktops (10+ Units) - $85.00 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
                <select id="selectDesktopPlus" name="" class="form-control-sm">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!-- Laptops (1-9 Units) -->
            <div class="form-row products">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="chkYes3">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="laptops" name="" value="laptops" />
                        Laptops (1-9 Units) - $250.00 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control-sm">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!-- Laptops (10+ Units) -->
            <div class="form-row products">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="chkYes4">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="laptopsPlus" name="" value="laptopsPlus"/>
                        Laptops (10+ Units) - $125.00 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control-sm">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!-- Microsoft Surface -->
            <div class="form-row products">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="chkYes5">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="msSurface" name="" value="msSurface" />
                        Microsoft Surface - $199.00 &emsp;&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control-sm">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!-- Apple iPad -->
            <div class="form-row products">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="chkYes6">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="appleIpad" name="" value="appleIpad" />
                        Apple iPad - $85.00 &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
                <select id="mySelect" name="" class="form-control-sm">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>


            <!-- Checkboxes for extra Items for Purchase (Desktop) -->
            <div id="chkYesText1" class="form-group">
                <label class=" font-weight-bold" for="checkboxes">Extra Items for Purchase
                    (Desktop)</label>
                <div>
                    <div class="extraItemsDesktop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-0">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="wirelessCard" id="wirelessCard" value="wirelessCard">
                            Wireless Card - $30.00
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extraItemsDesktop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-1">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="extraMemory" id="extraMemory" value="extraMemory">
                            Extra Memory (2GB) - $50.00
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extraItemsDesktop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-2">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="speakers" id="speakers" value="speakers">
                            Speakers - $30.00
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extraItemsDesktop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-3">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="surgeProtectors" id="surgeProtectors" value="surgeProtectors">
                            Surge Protectors - $5.00
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extraItemsDesktop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="flashDrive" id="flashDrive" value="flashDrive">
                            Flash Drive - $30.00
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extraItemsDesktop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-5">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="addSSD" id="addSSD" value="addSSD">
                            Add SSD (Solid State Drive) - $30.00
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Checkboxes for extra Items for Purchase (Laptop) -->
            <div id="chkYesText2" class="form-group">
                <label class="font-weight-bold" for="checkboxes">Extra Items for Purchase
                    (Laptop)</label>
                <div>
                    <div class="extraItemsLaptop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-0">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="wirelessCardLap" id="wirelessCardLap" value="wirelessCardLap">
                            Surge Protectors - $5.00
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extraItemsLaptop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-1">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="flashDriveLap" id="flashDriveLap" value="flashDriveLap">
                            Flash Drive - $30.00
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extraItemsLaptop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-2">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="addSSDLap" id="addSSDLap" value="addSSDLap">
                            Add SSD (Solid State Drive) - $30.00
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extraItemsLaptop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-3">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="extraMemoryLap" id="extraMemoryLap" value="extraMemoryLap">
                            Extra Memory (2GB) - $50.00
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extraItemsLaptop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="speakers" id="speakers" value="speakers">
                            Speakers - $30.00
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group border border-dark rounded py-3 px-5">
            <h3>Amount Due: <p id="amountDue">0</p>
            </h3>
        </div>
```

Comment: I feel like you posted this same question yesterday and we answered it yesterday.

Comment: my guess is `dTotal = Math.round(dTotal * iNumberofItems);` should not be that

Comment: @Scott well, I still have the problem when I put the codes altogether, It won't work properly.

Comment: I would return to yesterday's question then and update it rather than posting a new question.

Comment: @Scott I never thought I could do that. Good to know. Thanks

Comment: @epascarello `dTotal = Math.round(dTotal * iNumberofItems); ` works fine, I believe `dTotal = Math.round(dTotal * iNumberofItemsPlus);`  messes up the calculation..!

Comment: Please delete this question and go back to your other one and update it as necessary.

Comment: @Sam you are running `dTotal` against the total number that already exists, not the value of the checkbox. SO it is `(previous total + 85) * iNumberofItemsPlus` not `previous total + (85 * iNumberofItemsPlus)` The code should look more like `dTotal += Math.round(85 * iNumberofItemsPlus);`

Answer (score 1):

you are not setting the selectedOptionsPlus select to 1 when the check is clicked. This leads to multiplication by zero.

```
   document.getElementById("desktopsPlus").addEventListener("change", function () {
       selectOptions.value = 1;
      calculateTotal();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an order of operations problem. It works for the first one because the previous total is zero. It does not work for the second one if first is selected, because you are using that value in the calculation.

You are running dTotal against the total number that already exists, not the value of the checkbox. So it is `(previous_total + 85) * iNumberofItemsPlus` not `previous_total + (85 * iNumberofItemsPlus)`

```
var dTotal = 0;

if (desktopAddOn.checked) {
    var iNumberofItems = parseInt(selectOptions.options[selectOptions.selectedIndex].value);
    dTotal += Math.round(185 * iNumberofItems);
}

if (desktopPlusAddOn.checked) {
    var iNumberofItemsPlus = parseInt(selectOptionsPlus.options[selectOptionsPlus.selectedIndex].value);
    dTotal += Math.round(85 * iNumberofItemsPlus);
}

....
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. It doesn't reset the value, but still, it doesn't calculate the second checkbox with different quantity? I already have `var selectOptionsPlus = document.getElementById("selectDesktopPlus");` for the value of the options!